# How to interpret Debugging information?

Tags: android, location

This is actually two questions:

1. The first relates to my program
2. The second is a more general question regarding debugging.

In my code, I have two button listeners. When the first is clicked, the onClickListener creates the **locationlistener** as well as the **LocationManager** which requests updates from the locationlistener. (See code below.)

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)  getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationlistener);
```

On the click of the second button, I try to unregister the listener as follows:

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(locationlistener);
```

However, I end up with a force close and the following info in the debugger:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(310): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(310): java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(310):     at com.ryan.gcal.GRunCal$2.onClick(GRunCal.java:94)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(310):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(310):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(310):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(310):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(310):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(310):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(310):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(310):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(310):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(310):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(310):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 94 of my code, where the error originates, is where I tried to remove the location listener. So, I assume I am not removing the location listener properly, but I am not sure what is wrong.  My LocationManager is declared at the start of my code:

```
Locationmanager locationManager;
```

My first question is, what am I doing wrong in removing the listener? And secondly, can anyone provide some tips/advice on learning to interpret debug errors meaningfully?
Thanks.

Comment: how did you declare `locationlistener`?

Comment: I've updated the question to include my declaration of locationlistener

Comment: You need to show more detail, for example how you instantiate your locaionListener. It also looks like your formatting is messed up. Happened to me the other day, you need to cut the message into notepad, edit it and replace the whole question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either:

A) define the locationManager instance as a class variable, or retrieve it again in your onclick.

```
LocationManager locationManager;

public void onClick1()
{
    locationManager = (LocationManager)  getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationlistener);

}

public void onClick2()
{
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationlistener);
}
```

You need to make sure that in onClick1() instead of

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)  getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

you put

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)  getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Specifying LocationManager locationManager makes the scope of your declaration enclosed to the method its assign in, rather than in the scope of the class. This means in your 2nd click locationManager is infact null.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I didn't realize that by Specifying LocationManager again I would be changing the scope of the declaration.  Thankyou very much for your help Emile.  I will try and clean up my question above a bit more to clarify it for future users.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your second question. To understand what all the exceptions and errors mean you just have to consult the reference page which you can find at http://d.android.com. Also the exception/error message is of great help as it tells you what went wrong most of the times.

Also when looking at a stacktrace shows you the fully qualified class name (i.e. class name including the package name) and the method in which the exception happened or from which the exception got triggered and in parentheses you will again find the class name and the code line number where the exception got thrown.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks.  So for my exception, it's a classcastexception... Thrown when a program attempts to cast a an object to a type with which it is not compatible.  I declared it as a LocationListener, why would it need to be recast?

Comment: are you sure that the exception is caused by that line? can you post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: I have tried to simplify my code and put everything into the same activity.  I now get a nullpointer exception as per the edited post.

Answer (score 1):

Going by Octavians explanation:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(310): java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(310):     at    com.ryan.gcal.GRunCal$2.onClick(GRunCal.java:94)
```

Means in the onClick method defined in your GRunCal class, specifically at line 94, you are most likely calling a method upon a null value. This should be obvious once you check your code.

for example:

```
View myCustomComponent;
public void onClick(View v)
{
    myCustomComponent.doSomething();// Null pointer exception would be thrown. because myCustomComponent hasn't been assigned.
}
```

You could put a break point before line 94 and then watch the values of your method. Work back from there to discover what is actually failing.

After your edit.

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(286): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.content.Intent
```

I think, but can't be 100 sure that this is caused by the following sort of situation.

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    Thread nonsense = (Thread)v;
}
```

i.e. the above code is nonsense, pretty sure you can't cast a view as a thread, but the point is casting something as another type would throw such an error.